# Is there a way to use a Google Picker in Chrome Apps?

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-picker

I write a Chrome App and I'd like to use a Google Picker API. It seems that this API is available for web applications only. Is there some way to use it or I need to implement custom picker using Google Drive API?

Comment: Did you already try to use it? To verify/confirm that it is only for web apps?
By checking the [Google documentation of Chrome apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps), I think it is just like a web apps that has some development capacity. So maybe you can use Picker API here.

Comment: There main problem is that Picker API use GAPI js library. Seems that it doesn't supported in installed apps because it can't pass through all oauth authentication steps. Related issue: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/46